# Numerical String sorting in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to sort documents in mongo, based on multiple fields hierarchically.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Gdm_eM8j3Q is having sample data and the aggregate query that I have written.

Sorting of a string field(with numerical value) is giving wrong order

"000000000000008000001" is coming first followed by "000000000000001222223". Am I doing something wrong? Can someone please help?

Note: I do not want to use collation as it is a string and do not want to restrict the value only to numerical values.

Comment: Are you sure? When I run your sample, then `"000000000000001222223"` comes before `"000000000000008000001"`

Comment: Yes. If I run multiple times, the order differs !

Comment: Your aggregation pipeline looks a bit strange. You run `{$sort: {outer: 1}}` but in the next stage you project `outer: "$_id"`. Anyway, when I run it on my mongo shell, the order is always the same (and correct). Only in mongoplayground.net it changes. Where do you get this problem? Some drivers/API may rearrange the fields, because according to JSON specification, the order does not matter. MongoDB contradict to this definition, this may cause the mismatch.

Comment: The issue is in Mongo shell ( Mongo Compass 1.30.1 ) as well as from the Java code running on latest Mongo ( mongo-driver-sync 4.6.0 )

Comment: Regarding the comment about sort and project, is it fine if I sort after the final project ? In this case, the order seems to be fixed and always the same.   
    `{ $project: {
      _id: 0,
      outer: "$_id",
      innerData: 1,
      data: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "outer": 1,
      "innerKey": 1,
      "dataKey": 1
    }
  }`

Comment: You get this issue already with simplified `db.collection.aggregate([{ $sort: { outer: 1, inner: 1, dataNumber: 1 } }])` Maybe you need to open a ticket for it at MongoDB directly.